# Why in c# 2.135 is always rounded (using 2 decimals) to 2.13

Tags: c#, .net, rounding

When using `Math.Round(doubleValue, 2)` // ToEven by default

//       2.135 --> 2.13  why not 2.14?

//       3.135 --> 3.14

And when using AwayFromZero  2.135 rounds at 2.13 why not 2.14?

Comment: `2.135` is actually `2.13499999999999999....`

Comment: The exact value of (a double) `2.135` as a fraction is `1201898150554501/562949953421312`. The next value up is `2.1350000000000016` which rounds to `2.14`.

Comment: As @leppie pointed out, this is a representation issue, if you use `decimal` variables instead, rounded values will have the same decimal parts (for `2.135m and 3.135m`)

Comment: If you don't want to use decimal you could consider using integer values with an artificial moved decimal point (can't remember the proper name), so instead of 2.135 and 3.135 you'd use values 2135 and 3135. Just remember to divide by 1000 before producing your final result.

Comment: Because you should never use double and round to decimal places. Use decimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the question from your title:

2.135 is **not** always rounded(using 2 decimals) to 2.13, this just happens in your case because you are using a binary floating point data type. (As [leppie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15541/leppie) pointed out, 2.135 cannot be represented accurately as a double, please note also that [Microsoft seems to disinguish between `decimal` and `floating point types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx), even though decimal also fits the definition)

If you were however to use `decimal` as data type instead you will have consistent behaviour in rounding, you can compare the different outputs from [this snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8ooOLK) to verify:

```
decimal val1 = 2.135m;
decimal val2 = 3.135m;

Console.WriteLine("decimal val1({0}) rounded = {1}", val1, Math.Round(val1, 2));
Console.WriteLine("decimal val2({0}) rounded = {1}", val2, Math.Round(val2, 2));

double dval1 = 2.135;
double dval2 = 3.135;

Console.WriteLine("double val1({0}) rounded = {1}", dval1, Math.Round(dval1, 2));
Console.WriteLine("double val2({0}) rounded = {1}", dval2, Math.Round(dval2, 2));
```

Comment: Because you are using a *binary* floating point type. Decimal is a floating point type as well.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Hm, your statement makes sense, I was about to edit it then I read the first sentence [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) which makes me think microsoft distinguishes between `decimal` and `floating point data types` in general, maybe you got another reference for further reading?

Comment: MSDN may mislabel as it likes. But floating point numbers have a general definition, and decimal fits that definition since it has a variable exponent to scale by. For example wikipedia describes floating point as "A number is, in general, represented approximately to a fixed number of significant digits (the significand) and scaled using an exponent".

Comment: @CodesInChaos To the average user, a floating point is a structure with variable precision - `decimal` is this. However, a `float` is a structure that implements the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic. `decimal` does not and the distinction is important - binary coded decimal has a different storage scheme and will serialize differently.